# Split one column to multiple columns

Tags: java, delimiter

I have one column contains below data . want to split data in to multiple columns using java code . problem i am facing was in string I have double quotes with comma it was falling in to another column. I have to split data as follows(target). Can any one help to fix this ?

I/P:
Column:

abc,"test,data",valid

xyz,"sample,data",invalid

Target:

Col1|Col2|Col3

abc|"test,data"|valid

xyz|"sample_data"|invalid

Comment: will your structure always `text,"text",test"`? if it will do... try this logic `"test1,\"teste2,teste3\",teste4".replace(",\"", "#\"").replace("\",", "\"#").replace(",", "_").replace("#", ",")`... if dosen't you need try mathers group in Pattern java

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you use a library to handle instead doing it yourself.
I guess your data is in CSV format, so you should take a look at common-csv.

You can resolve your problem with simple code:

```
CSVParser records = CSVParser.parse("abc,\"test,data\",valid", CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : records) {
    for (String value : csvRecord) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abc
test,data
valid
```

Read more at https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv